# "Moonshine" basics?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-forms

Having browsed recently a bit about "moonshine", which looks to me like some weird surrealist landscape, I wonder if: 1. sporadic groups could be seen as seemingly isolated special points of some connecting generic structure, and 2. one has distilled the mathematics out of the building lot "string theory", so that some less weird looking picture of those strange connections can come up. Exists work in those direction?